# getting error in ffmpeg complex filter init

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg

I am trying to build an application using ffmpeg library and that app will scale video and show volume bars (using showvolume filter) over scaled video.

When I use ffmpeg command at that time it works like charm but somehow I cant make it work in c program, please help me to solve this issue

I am trying to set complex filter in two different methods:

1. using avfilter_graph_parse2 function
2. manually link each filters

**method 1 Error:**

`[Parsed_showvolume_0 @ 0x1aca580] Format change is not supported
Error while feeding the filtergraph`

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZvpX.png)

[filter graph](https://pastebin.com/GgHDvh8P)

**method 2 Error:**

`[afifo @ 0x9cd880] Format change is not supported
Error while feeding the filtergraph`

[output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JR30E.png)

[filter graph](https://pastebin.com/dVhx1uTJ)

**C Code:**
[main.c file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6ed0ubfm759hpd/main.c?dl=0)

**ffmpeg version:**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/eclipse-workspace/compexFilterTest/Debug$ ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version git-2018-07-11-bd8a5c6 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1) 20160609
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-version3 --enable-pic --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-openssl --enable-shared --enable-libass --enable-libvpx --enable-libx265 --enable-libtwolame
libavutil      56. 18.102 / 56. 18.102
libavcodec     58. 21.104 / 58. 21.104
libavformat    58. 17.101 / 58. 17.101
libavdevice    58.  4.101 / 58.  4.101
libavfilter     7. 25.100 /  7. 25.100
libswscale      5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100
libswresample   3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
libpostproc    55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
```

**ffmpeg CLI command:**

```
ffmpeg -loglevel 40 -i test.ts  -filter_complex "[0:a]afifo,showvolume=w=240:h=20:o=1:f=0.50:r=25[vol0];nullsrc=size=320x240[base1];[0:v]fifo,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=320x240[w0h0];[w0h0][vol0]overlay=eval=0:x=280[w0h0a];[base1][w0h0a]overlay=shortest=1:eval=0" -vcodec h264 -profile:v main -level 4 -metadata service_provider=testScreenProvider  -metadata service_name=testScreen  -f mpegts -y test123.ts
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Audio filters don't support change in stream properties mid-way. The filtergraph needs to be reinitialized. See ifilter_send_frame() in ffmpeg.c.

Comment: @Gyan I might be wrong but i dont see format change in filter_graph. can you please be more specific?

Comment: @Gyan you were right about audio filters dont supports change in stream mid way but that wasnt the problem in my case. Problem was ffmpeg was probing fltp audio format but actually audio was s16p. so i changed that and that error has gone. Thank you. But now i cant get video frames from filter_graph output. do anyone have any idea what i did wrong?